# Is it possible to send custom headers with an XHR ("Ajax" request)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, header, xmlhttprequest

I'm working with an API which needs extra security information sent along with an HTTP request as meta-information in headers. Is it possible to set those in an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: To anyone visiting from Google: setRequestHeader is now part of the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, see ["The setRequestHeader() method"](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20121206/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) of the current XMLHttpRequest working draft of 6 December 2012.